# How can i enable Drag & Drop in Highcharts organization-charts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, drag-and-drop

I need to set up a Highcharts chart of type "organization" which should support Drag & Drop the Nodes on each other (to move the nodes inside the tree).

Currently, I got an "organization" chart which displays all the needed information.

I tried to use the `Highcharts.plotOptions.series.dragDrop`-Events but that wasn't working at all.
I also tried to use `Highcharts.series[organization].dataLabels.nodeFormatter`-Callback to replace the outer div by a div with attributes: `draggable="true" ondragstart="fun1(event)" ondrag="fun2(event)" ondrop="fun3(event)" ondragover="func(event)"`

I just used the functions from w3schools:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

But that wasn't working either.
So now I am stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that drag and drop is not implemented on **Organizations** chart type.
You can read the thread in official highcharts forum or on github issues.

Follow the conversation on: 
[Highcharts forum](https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=42399) and
[Github issues](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11615)

Comment: I see ... so yeah i think we just need to wait here :)