# Drag and drop feature for Highcharts Organisation chart

Tags: highcharts

Is the drag and drop feature available for organization charts?

[image]

Comment: See this ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855200/how-can-i-enable-drag-drop-in-highcharts-organization-charts

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i enable Drag & Drop in Highcharts organization-charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59855200/how-can-i-enable-drag-drop-in-highcharts-organization-charts)